# NSView's Drawing Context

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Is it safe to get a NSView's CGContext from `-drawRect:` and use it to later perform more drawing? In a simple test like this one:

```
CGContextRef context = NULL;

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)r
{
    if (!context)
        context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
}

- (void)drawSomething
{
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 100));
    CGContextFlush(context);
}
```

everything seems to work when `-drawSomething` is called, but is it guaranteed that the context won't change?

As you can see and might guess, I'm trying to bypass the standard way of drawing using `-drawRect:`. It works just nicely for a myriad of occasions, but a more procedural way of drawing would make life easier in my particular case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not do this. The context is not guaranteed to exist outside of `drawRect:` and the fact that your drawing code is working is a happy accident. Do not rely on this behaviour.

If you need to force drawing at any point, you should call `display` on the view, which will in turn call `drawRect:`.

Comment: It's hard to figure that out the first time when you deal with NSGraphicsContext. Thank you for your answer and pointing this out to many people!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `lockFocus:` if you want to draw outside `drawRect:`
Here is the excerpt from documentation of [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html):

> If you don’t use a display... method to draw an NSView object, you
>   must invoke lockFocus before invoking methods that send commands to
>   the window server, and must balance it with an unlockFocus message
>   when finished.
>
> Hiding or miniaturizing a one-shot window causes the backing store for
>   that window to be released. If you don’t use the standard display
>   mechanism to draw, you should use lockFocusIfCanDraw rather than
>   lockFocus if there is a chance of drawing while the window is either
>   miniaturized or hidden.